# Euclidean Algorithm Computation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Given positive integers $a,b,c,d$, find all possible values of $|ad - bc|$ for which $$\gcd (an + b, cn + d) = m$$ for positive integer $m>1$, has infinitely many values for $n$.

My progress thus far: I tried working with small values of $a,b,c,d$ first. It appears to me that it is impossible for a the numbers to be $a>b>c = d$ or $a> b = c = d$ or $a=b=c=d$ (or some permutation but with those relations), but I'm not sure. For example, say we take $(1,1,1,2)$ (a quadruple representing $(a,b,c,d)$), then by the Euclidean algorithm, we have that 
$$\gcd (n + 1 , n+2) = \gcd(n+1, 1) = m,$$
which consequently doesn't have any solutions unless $m=1.$ But I'm not quite sure if this is correct -- I can't prove that those relationships between the variables are true -- nor can I make much further progress than just playing with numbers. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Bezout's identity may be helpful...

Comment: Sure, so by Bezout, we would have that $(an+b)x+(cn+d)y=m$. We could rearrange that to solve for $n$, but how does that help? I fail to see how this really helps... could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for some positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ that there's an $m \gt 1$ such that

$$m = \gcd(an + b, cn + d) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

for at least one integer $n$. Thus, for some integers $e$ and $f$ with $\gcd(e,f) = 1$, you get

$$an + b = em \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$cn + d = fm \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Next, $a$ times \eqref{eq3A} minus $c$ times \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$ad - bc = (af - ec)m \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This shows $m \mid ad - bc$. If $ad - bc = 0$, then for $m \gt 1$, you have $af - ec = 0 \implies af = ec$. Since $\gcd(e,f) = 1$, then $e \mid a$ and $f \mid c$. Since $a$ and $c$ are fixed integers, there are only a finite # of possible values for $e$ and $f$, so there can't be an infinite # of $n$.

From this point on, assume $ad - bc \neq 0$. Next, let

$$g = \gcd(a,c) \implies a = gh, c = gi, \gcd(h,i) = 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Note $af - ec$ must be an integral multiple of $g$, so $m \mid \frac{ad - bc}{\gcd(a,c)} = hd - ib$. Thus, $m \gt 1$ requires $|ad - bc| \gt \gcd(a,c) = g$. Assume this is true, i.e., a required condition is that

$$\frac{|ad - bc|}{\gcd(a,c)} \gt 1 \tag{5B}\label{eq5B}$$

Also have

$$m = |hd - ib| \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Next, have

$$j = \text{sgn}(ad - bc) \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

where $\text{sgn}$ is the [Sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), meaning it's $1$ if the argument is positive, $0$ if it's $0$, else its $-1$ if it's negative. From \eqref{eq4A}, \eqref{eq5A}, \eqref{eq6A} and \eqref{eq7A} you get

$$hf - ei = j \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Since $\gcd(h,i) = 1$, [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) guarantees there's a solution, with the full set of solutions being

$$e = e_0 + kh \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

$$f = f_0 + ki \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

for some fixed integers $e_0$ and $f_0$, and $k$ being any integer. Note substituting \eqref{eq9A} and \eqref{eq10A} into \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A} results in $2$ linear equations in the $2$ unknowns of $k$ and $n$. If the $2$ equations were linearly independent, you'd get just one solution for $k$ and $n$. Thus, an infinite # of values of $n$ requires the $2$ equations to be *linearly dependent*, i.e., one is a multiple of the other. To check on this, substitute \eqref{eq5A}, \eqref{eq9A} and \eqref{eq10A} into \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A}, move the right side terms to the left, and gather the terms involving $n$ and $k$ together to get

$$(gh)n + (-hm)k + (b - e_0 m) = 0 \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

$$(gi)n + (-im)k + (d - f_0 m) = 0 \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

As can be seen, multiplying \eqref{eq11A} by $i$ and \eqref{eq12A} by $h$ causes the first $2$ terms to be equal. Thus, you also require (where \eqref{eq8A} is used below) that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
i(b - e_0 m) & = h(d - f_0 m) \\
ib - (ie_0)m & = hd - (hf_0)m \\
(hf_0 - ie_0)m & = hd - ib \\
jm & = hd - ib
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$

This matches \eqref{eq6A}, so there's no extra requirement for \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A} to be multiples of each other. Thus, just use the updated version of \eqref{eq2A} in \eqref{eq11A} to get

$$(gh)n = (hm)k + (e_0 m - b) \tag{14}\label{eq14A}$$

From \eqref{eq6A} and \eqref{eq7A}, you have $m = j(hd - ib)$, so this means

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
e_0 m - b & = e_0 j(hd - ib) - b \\
& = (e_0 jd)h - b(je_0 i + 1) \\
& = (e_0 jd)h - jb(e_0 i + j) \\
& = (e_0 jd)h - jb(h f_0) \\
& = hj(e_0 d - f_0)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{15}\label{eq15A}$$

where \eqref{eq8A} is used in the second last step. Thus, substituting this into \eqref{eq14A} and dividing by the common factor of $h$ gives

$$(g)n = (m)k + j(e_0 d - f_0) \tag{16}\label{eq16A}$$

Next, let

$$q = \gcd(g,m) \implies g = qr, m = qs, \gcd(r,s) = 1 \tag{17}\label{eq17A}$$

This also requires that $q \mid e_0 d - f_0$. If not, then let $p$ be a prime where $p \mid q$ but $p \not\mid e_0 d - f_0$. Consider if changing $e_0$ and $f_0$ will fix this. Let $e_0 = e_1 + k_1 h$ and $f_0 = f_1 + k_1 i$ where $e_1$ and $f_1$ also satisfy \eqref{eq8A} and $k_1$ is any integer. Then $e_0 d - f_0 = (e_1 + k_1 h)d - (f_1 + k_1 i) = e_1 d - f_1 + k_1(hd - i)$. If $p \mid e_1 d - f_1$, you can have $k_1$ be any multiple of $p$. Otherwise, as long as $p \not\mid hd - i$, you can choose a $k_1$ so the result is a multiple of $p$. This is a limitation which needs to be accounted for, with possibly changing the value of $m$ used initially helping in some cases. I'll leave this to you to check on & finish.

Otherwise, with $q \mid e_0 d - f_0$, you then have

$$e_0 d - f_0 = uq \tag{18}\label{eq18A}$$

Substituting \eqref{eq17A} and \eqref{eq18A} into \eqref{eq16A}, dividing by the common factor of $q$ and rearranging gives

$$rn - sk = u \tag{19}\label{eq19A}$$

Since $\gcd(r,s) = 1$, Bézout's lemma guarantees there's a solution, actually an infinite # of them, for $n_0$ and $k_0$ in

$$rn_0 + s(-k_0) = 1 \tag{20}\label{eq20A}$$

Thus, multiplying both sides by $u$ comparing to \eqref{eq19A} shows there's an infinite # of $n = un_0$ and $k = uk_0$.

In this solution, the only required condition on $|ad - bc|$ for there to be an infinite # of $n$, apart from any extra conditions from the limitation described in the paragraph between \eqref{eq17A} and \eqref{eq18A}, is that given in \eqref{eq5B}.

Comment: I have a couple of questions. First, is it necessary to include the sign function at all? Could we not just consider $|ad-bc|$ in all of the computations? Also, while I understand all the steps, I have a concern with the assumption that $m = |hd - bi|,$ wouldn't we also need to consider all divisors of $m$ being equal to $|hd-bi|?$ Or is there a reason that we can only conideer the case that $m = |hd- bi|$ and be done with just that?  Finally, I would appreciate some further directions as to what to do next... Sorry if my questions are stupid

Comment: @Omicron9Gamma Your questions are definitely not stupid. When I taught first year university integral calculus many years ago, I told my class there's no such thing as a stupid question, only stupid answers. This, of course, is not strictly true, but I trust you get the idea. As for using the sign function, since $m$ is required to be positive, & by convention the $\gcd$ value is always non-negative, even if one or both values passed to it are negative, then since $ad - bc$ can be either positive or negative, I used the sign function. As for using $|ad - bc|$ in all computations instead, ...

Comment: @Omicron9Gamma (cont.) keep in mind that $ad - bc$ shows up, without absolute values, in my equation (4). If I used absolute values, with no use of the sign function, then I would need to use absolute values around the other variables. Thus, I would need to do this in their original equations. However, when I tried to manipulate these equations, e.g., add or subtract them, I would need to handle $2$ cases, so it would involve more work. As such, I don't recommend what you're suggesting. Regarding your second question, the problem only asks to find *one* value of $m \gt 1$ for which there ...

Comment: @Omicron9Gamma (cont.) are an infinite # of $n$. Choosing just the one $m$ I know would work, i.e., the maximum one (since if $m$ were a prime, e.g., $2$, there would only be one choice anyway) makes the calculations somewhat simpler as, otherwise, I would need to deal with another variable. As long as this maximal $m$ works, that's all which is needed. Nonetheless, as I explain in the paragraph between (17) and (18), there's a potential issue which may require you to choose a different $m$. As I've already spent many hours on this (more than on any other answer), I'll leave this to you. ...

Comment: @Omicron9Gamma Regarding what to do next, I've made some significant updates to the answer. I've replaced the last part with a different approach, and provided all of the required details, apart from the one potential issue I mentioned in my previous comment. I hope everything I wrote makes sense and you're able to handle the last few steps yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses and detailed answer! I think I proved the final part that you left for me. It appears that the conclusion is that the sum across all $|ad - bc|$ is infinite, correct? I ended up writing a program for this with a sample $m = 2019$ (because why not?) and it appears that the sum always approaches infinity. Would this be a correct conclusion?

Comment: @Omicron9Gamma You're welcome for the help. Congratulations on proving the final part. Regarding the possible values of |ad-bc| which are allowed, don't forget it can't be $0$, & I also stated between my (5) and (6) that "Thus, $m \gt 1$ requires $|ad - bc| \gt \gcd(a,c) = g$." In particular, this means that $\frac{|ad-bc|}{\gcd(a,c)} \ge 2$ since it requires that $m \ge 2$. This is the only condition my part of the solution imposes so, if the final part doesn't require any more limitations, that would be it. Your sample $m=2019$ undoubtedly satisfies this limitation, which is why it worked.

Comment: @Omicron9Gamma I've extended my answer somewhat to make this required condition more explicit, as it's basically what the problem is asking for, by adding (5B) (I didn't feel like renumbering all of the later equations) and a final sentence stating (5B) gives the required condition.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying again! One last question, though, in the last sentence where you write "In this solution, the only required condition on $|ac -  bd|$..." do you mean instead $|ad - bc|?$

Comment: @Omicron9Gamma You're welcome for the extra clarifications. As for my last sentence, you're right about the expression mistake. It's a typo which I've now fixed. Thanks for noticing it.